# Submit and hide all labels with a containing form chekbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I'd like to create a function that that submits all the formularies with a checkbox checked and hides with their respective div tags

I put the following code as an example

```
<html>
<script>
    //the jquery function to submit all forms 
    $(function () {
        $(".formerasemessage").each(function () {
            var par_div = $(this).closest(".demo"); //finding the closest div
            $(this).validate({
                submitHandler: function (formbeingsubmitted) {
                    $.post('remove.php', $(formbeingsubmitted).serialize(), function (data) {
                        $(formbeingsubmitted).hide("slow");
                        par_div.hide('slow'); //hide the div
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <form method="post" class="formerasemessage">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem"></form>
    </div>
    <div class="demo">
        <form method="post" class="formerasemessage">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1"></form>
    </div>
    <div class="demo">
        <form method="post" class="formerasemessage">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2"></form>
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Submit all checked">
</body>
</html>
```

I need to reprogram the function Jquery so that it can perform the desired function.

the visual result would be something like this:

[image: that's my inbox of Outlook]

that's my inbox of Outlook, checked my mails and then I click in 'remove' and my emails are hidden and deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(":checked",".formerasemessage").each(function () {
            var par_div = $(this).closest(".demo"); //finding the closest div
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
         form.validate({submitHandler: function () {
          $.post('remove.php', form.serialize(), function (data) {
           form.hide("slow"); 
            par_div.hide('slow'); //hide the div
           });
          }
         }).submit();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i refresh the question, i need submit al forms checked with a only buttom

Comment: perss the buttom Submit all checked

Comment: added
you mean "button"

Why are you using validate here ? not sure on the use case , seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

You could call the input using document.getElementById("inputid").value. To hide anything, use a css code :
   #inputid {visibility: hidden}
You can also archieve the same effect using javascript.
Archive to execute a js function with for instance : I can be clicked

You'll find several options online (W3schools) such as onclick, onmousein, onchange ...